# Rewrite subpage to subdomain in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want rewrite my subpage to subdomain in Apache server. Something like this:

```
www.example.com/mycats/news
```

to

```
www.news.example.com
```

I found this code but not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).example.com$ [NC]
```

And what is need except the code? Apache and wildcard mod?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mycats/(.+)/? http://www.$1.example.com/ [L,R]
```

If you don't want to externally redirect the browser, remove the `R`

Comment: What error(s) do you get? This works exactly as you've described in your question in my .htaccess file.